# How to push an array into a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, push-back

I didn't find in the internet something that answers specifically my question.

I have a hash as follows:

```
hash = {[1111, 4, 20]}
```

And i want to push another array (`[3333, 2, 70]`) to that hash to get something like:

```
hash = {[1111, 4, 20], [3333, 2, 70]}
```

How can achieve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't really see how that's a hash. Where are the keys and the values?

Comment: The keys are implicit. I need them as I'm going to iterate using an `each`

Comment: I think you just want nested arrays... `[[1111, 4, 20]] << [3333, 2, 70] # [[1111, 4, 20], [3333, 2, 70]]`

Comment: *"I have a hash as follows: `hash = {[1111, 4, 20]}`"* - there's no such hash, that gives a syntax error. Please show your actual code.

Comment: @RailsRails ok, let's say keys are implicit - at least implicit for us, the nebbish mortals :) but what about the second array? do you want to append this array to the implicit key's value array, or  as any other explicit-but-implicit key's value?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to have here is not a Hash. It's an Array of arrays.
The syntax you wrote is not a valid Ruby syntax.

To add an item to an Array use [<<](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C).

For example:

```
array = [[1111, 4, 20]]
```

To add an item you do:

```
array << [3333, 2, 70]
```

your array would be:

```
[[1111, 4, 20], [3333, 2, 70]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work. You probably want store those arrays in another array like this:

```
a = [[1111, 4, 20]]
a << [3333, 2, 70]
=> [[1111, 4, 20], [3333, 2, 70]]
```

Is that what you were looking for?

"A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of unique keys and their values. Also called associative arrays, they are similar to Arrays, but where an Array uses integers as its index, a Hash allows you to use any object type."

Please read more about ruby arrays and hashes:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html